# Java ArrayList sort в ранних версиях

Tags: java, android, сортировка, arraylist

Пытаюсь отсортировать ArrayList. Жалуется, что в api не поддерживается `compare`. Как можно выполнить сортировку в более ранних версиях андроида?

```
Collections.sort(MyList, new Comparator<MyModel>() { 
    @Override
    public int compare(MyModel o1, MyModel o2) {
        return Boolean.compare(o1.isDeleted(),o2.isDeleted());
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Метод:

```
public static int compare (boolean x, boolean y)
```

класса `Boolean` стал доступен в API level 19.

На более ранних версиях можно использовать метод:

```
public int compareTo (Boolean b)
```

этого же класса, который доступен начиная с API level 1. Пример:

```
boolean b1 = true;
boolean b2 = false;
int result = Boolean.valueOf(b1).compareTo(b2);
```

В Вашем случае:

```
Collections.sort(MyList, new Comparator<MyModel>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(MyModel o1, MyModel o2) {
        return Boolean.valueOf(o1.isDeleted()).compareTo(o2.isDeleted());
    }
});
```

Или же можно написать свою реализацию сравнения, так как в данном случае это довольно просто.

Comment: вопрос немного не по теме. подскажите когда в андроид можно будет использовать java8?)

Comment: @БорисовМакс, [Некоторые фичи](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support.html) можно уже сейчас использовать.

Comment: через RetroLambda?)

Comment: @БорисовМакс, С помощью нее в том числе.

Comment: @post_zeew по данной ссылке наоборот как перейти с retrolambda на встроенное

Answer (score 4):

```
Collections.sort(MyList, new Comparator<MyModel>() { 
    @Override
    public int compare(MyModel o1, MyModel o2) {
        return (o1.isDeleted() == o2.isDeleted()) ? 0 : (o1.isDeleted() ? 1 : -1);
    }
});
```

Comment: Отличный ответ, ещё, мне кажется, было бы круто объяснение добавить

Comment: если o1 == o2 возвращает 1, если o1>o2, то 1, если о1 <о2, то -1